# How to get current user in hsqldb, like we use sys_context in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hsqldb, hypersql

How to get current user in hsqldb, like we use sys_context in oracle.

What's the syntax to get current logged-in user in hsqldb?

Comment: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html mentions current_user etc.

Answer (score 0):

The function is `CURRENT_USER` and is listed among the "System Functions" http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#bfc_system_functions.